# Trying to write query of most popular product (meaning product with most distinct customers) super stuck. without using view

Tags: sql

this is the schema
Customer(CID,Name,City,State)
Order(OID,CID,Date)
Product(PID,ProductName,Price)
LineItem(LID,OID,PID,Number,TotalPrice),

Answer (score 0):

```
    with mostCustomers (pid, cnt) as
    (
       select 
    li.PID, count(distinct o.CID) customers
    from LineItem li
    inner join order o on o.OID = li.OID
    group by li.PID
),

    maxCustomers (customers) as (select max(customers) from mostCustomers)
        select p.ProductName
        from mostCustomers mc
        inner join maxCustomers mx on mx customers = mc.customers
        inner join product p on p.PID = mc.PID;
```

You should give sample data and expected output. Also you should have tagged your question with the backend you are using. Above query would work for most but not all.
Please do that next time.